# SNMP Send Message to the source

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap, snmpd

I want to send message to the where the snmp trap is came from, using udp port 161. Like "Hi, your trap is came!". Is it possible?

And if I couldn't do it, do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: No. TRAP is strictly a one way train, and the agent does not expect any followup. If you do want to acknowledge, let the agent send INFORM instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying. So how can i let the agent send inform?

Comment: Only who configured that agent knows whether a change can be made and how. If you work for a company, that should be your network administrators.